# Excel counting checkboxes in every second column

Tags: excel, counting, formulas

Take a look at the screenshot:

[image: late and absent tracker]

I am trying to count in column B the number of checked boxes (with TRUE value) in columns ABSENT and the same thing in column C for LATE.

Is there any simple way I can do it?

Thank you,
Pawel

Comment: Do those check boxes have 0/1 values behind them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`COUNTIFS`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countifs.php) function for this. Put the following formulas in the indicated cells:

**B4**

```
=COUNTIFS(D$2:ZZ$2, "ABSENT", D4:ZZ4, TRUE)
```

**C4**

```
=COUNTIFS(D$2:ZZ$2, "LATE", D4:ZZ4, TRUE)
```

You can copy these cells down the B and C column to apply the same formula there.

This is what happens in *B4*:

The columns *D* to *ZZ* are scanned for the combination of the following two conditions:

- row $2 has the value "ABSENT"
- row 4 (the same row as where the formula is) has the value *true*

The columns are counted where both of these conditions are true.